# How I can use refs to change styling class in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, refs

I'm trying to change background of a `div` when color value changes. Here is my function which receives color value:

```
ChangeColor(oColor) {
    this.props.ChangeColor(oColor);
    console.log("Refs: ", this.refs.colorPicker.className);
  },
```

Here is css class

```
.colorPicker {
    padding-right: 25px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

and here is my div element whose background needs to update on run-time.

```
<div ref='colorPicker' className={this.GetClass("colorPicker")}  />
```

I'm not sure about refs synatx so please help to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found it. Here is answer:

```
  ChangeColor(oColor) {
    this.props.ChangeColor(oColor);
    this.refs.colorPicker.style.background = oColor; //this is how background will be updated

  },
```

Comment: Can someone elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Just one more thing: mutating one of the the style object's properties is very slow. You should wrap this is request in a [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) call

Comment: Especially if the style you are changing is a transformation (i.e. `translate`, `top`, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

If somebody is looking for the hooks version

```html
export const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const divRef: = useRef(null);
  
  yourTriggerEvent = () => {
    divRef.current.style.background = 'red';
  }
  
  return (
    <div ref={divRef}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can change the color of the div with the ref element. For example:

```
const myReference = this.colorPicker.current // The DOM element
myReference.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // The style you want to apply
```